# How to Cache Pageable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I am trying to cache `Pageable` in Spring Boot. How do I handle caching for each page passed in pageable object?

```
@Service
public class MarketServiceImpl implements MarketService {

@Autowired
MarketDao marketDao;

@Cacheable(value = "marketData" key=?)
public Page<StockMarkets>  findAllMarket(Pageable pageable){
    return marketDao.findAll(pageable);
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't provide any key. It will automatically create a composite key. Bdw, this is not an efficient way to handle cache with Pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question here is somewhat ambiguous, at least to me.

You said, "*I am trying to cache Pageable in Spring Boot...*"

And then go onto show the code snippet with an `@Cacheable` method signature:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "marketData" key=?)
public Page<StockMarkets>  findAllMarket(Pageable pageable){
    return marketDao.findAll(pageable);
}
```

With the `key` attribute of the `@Cacheable` annotation declared on your `findAllMarket(..)` service method set to `?`, I assume you are not sure what the value of this `key` attribute should be?

Well, first of all, and technically, you do not even need to set the `key` attribute since Spring Framework's caching infrastructure will, by DEFAULT, "derive" a key from the `@Cacheable` method signature (i.e. `findAllMarket(:Pageable)`), using the arguments passed to the method parameters of the `@Cacheable` method (again, `findAllMarket(:Pageable)`), and in this case, that means the `Pageable` (request) object.

> TIP: See Spring Framework's Cache Abstraction documentation on "[Default key Generation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key)", for more details.

> TIP: You can also "customize" the key generation as well, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key).

So, Spring's caching infrastructure will use the `Pageable` parameter argument as the "key" in the cache entry, mapped to the `Page<StockMarkets>` object (that will be the cache entry value) returned by the method.

So, the outcome of the `findAllMarket(:Pageable)` method call will result in a cache entry stored in your "*marketData*" cache similar to:

`marketData` cache

```
KEY           | VALUE
--------------|------------------------
Pageable@1234 | Page<StockMarkets>@9876
```

This will be `true` for every `Pageable` (request) object passed to the `@Cacheable` `findAllMarket(..)` service method, unless the `Pageable` object is logically and semantically "*equal*", then the "cached" entry (i.e. `Page<StockMarkets>`) will be returned.

Fortunately, Spring Data's `Pageable` interface implementations (e.g. `PageRequest`; see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)) do override the Object `equals` and `hashCode` methods, so they are acceptable for use as "cache keys".

Keep in mind that any object used as a cache key should most definitely override the `java.lang.Object`, `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` methods, always. Caches are just glorified `Map` (data structures) after all.

Hope this makes sense.

Good luck!