# How to pass key to @Cacheable annotation in a dynamic fashion during pagination

Tags: caching, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

How to construct cache key for the following call, so that cache is reused for all scenarios while paginating, if I don't use Cacheable annotation will it still annotate by generating keys dynamically. This is the existing code which forms key dynamically

```
@Cacheable(value = "states", key = "#country + '_' + #pageable.pageNumber + '_' + #pageable.pageSize")
public Page<List<String>> findStatesByName(String country, Pageable pageable) {
    Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("state"));
    PageRequest pr = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), sort);
    Page<List<String>> states = countryRepository.findStatesByName(country, pageable);

    return states;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Cache Pageable in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835121/how-to-cache-pageable-in-spring-boot)